# How to change the 'micropost feed' URL from Rails Tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm following Michael Hartl's book 'Rails Tutorial' and need to change the logged in URL to render at `/members` instead of at the site's root.

I've tried changing home.html.erb from:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-4">
      <section class="user_info">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>
      <section class="stats">
        <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      </section>
      <section class="micropost_form">
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
      <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'covers/non_logged_in_home' %>
<% end %>
```

to

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%= render 'members/index' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'covers/non_logged_in_home' %>
<% end %>
```

and creating a new partial at views/members/ with he contents extracted from above like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-md-4">
      <section class="user_info">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>
      <section class="stats">
        <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      </section>
      <section class="micropost_form">
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h3>Micropost Feed</h3>
      <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

after doing this the micropost feed still works as usual, but remains in the site's root.  I figure it's a routing issue but am not sure how to handle it as the only routing info in routes.rb for microposts is:

```
resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
```

**Update:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'members/index' #just added; didn't work.

  get 'covers/new_cover' => 'covers#new_cover', :as => :new_cover

  get 'covers/home'

  get 'covers/new'

  get 'covers/create'

  get 'covers/destroy'

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'account_activations/edit'

  get 'sessions/new' 

  root                'covers#home'
  get    'profile'    => 'static_pages#profile'
  get    'tours'   => 'static_pages#tours'
  get    'blog'   => 'static_pages#blog'
  get    'reviews'   => 'static_pages#reviews'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  # resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]

  resources :covers, only: [:home, :index, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

**Update 2:**

When updating the route to

```
get 'members' => 'members#index'
```

as correctly suggested by @Arslan, the routing succeeds but the following error is returned in its place:

```
ArgumentError in MembersController#index
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Further investigation shows this error is caused by one or both of the following render statements contained in `app/views/members/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
```

Contents of these files is:

```
# _micropost_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost (420 chars max)..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function() {
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

and

```
# _feed.html.erb
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You want to change the route for the time when user logs in the site?

Comment: @ArslanAli, Yes, I want to route logged in users to `/members` instead of `/` and have the micropost feed load there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `SesssionController` class, you can change the `redirect` method to point to `/members`:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

# other code
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to '/members'
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Now, whenever a use successfully logs in your site, he/she will be redirected to `/members` page.

**Edit:**

`get 'members/index'` this will work if you have a class named `MembersController`, and in that class a method named `index`. Along with, you should also have a view at `app/views/members/index.htmlerb`.

And make it explicit like following:

```
get 'members/index' => 'members#index'
```

But if you want to invoke any method of any other controller, you can do:

```
get 'members/index' => 'any_other_controller#any_method' 
# Remember controller name should be in plural: 'members', 'users'
```

Comment: When he just logs into the site.  I realise you meant the `SessionsController` now.  Thanks!

Comment: It loads `http://localhost:3000/members` properly now but throws a routing error instead of rendering the micropost feed. `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/members"):`

Comment: Can you post your route file in your question?

Comment: I generated a members controller with an index definition but am still getting the routing error `(No route matches [GET] "/members"):` with the route set as `get 'members/index' => 'members#index'`

Comment: Change `get 'members/index' => 'members#index'` to just `get 'members' => 'members#index'`

Comment: Thanks for your patience Arslan.  That's much closer, it gets past the routing error, but returns `ArgumentError in MembersController#index`.  When I change the route to `get 'members' => 'microposts#create'` it returns `param is missing or the value is empty: micropost`

Comment: That is obvious. You need to send `params` to `create` method which you are sending right now. You can use a `form` to send `params` to the `create` method.

Comment: My bad, Arslan.  It is indeed obvious. :) I was just trying to get at the methods in microposts_controller as the `'members/index' => 'members#index` route just returned `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`.  I've narrowed the cause of this error to two renders in `views/members/index.html.erb`, in particular `render 'shared/micropost_form'` and `render 'shared/feed'`.  I have added info to my post.